# problems importing sub packages in python: how should I write the __init__.py files

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, virtualenv, init

I am new to building packages so bear with me. I am having a problem importing the subpackages of my latest python project.

My directory structure is the following:

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── subpackage_a
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── functions_a.py
│   └── subpackage_b
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── functions_b.py
└── setup.py
```

The files look as follows

> setup.py
>   :

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='test_package',
      version='0.3',
      description='',
      author='me',
      packages=['package']
      )
```

**package/__init__.py**: empty.

**subpackage_a/__init__.py**: `from .functions_a import *`

**subpackage_b/__init__.py**: `from .functions_b import *`

**functions_a.py**

contains

```
def hello_world_a():

    print('hello its a')
```

and **functions_b.py** contains

```
def hello_world_b():

    print('hello its b')
```

Now  I open a `virtualenv` go to the **setup.py**'s directory and I `pip install .`. I was expecting to access the functions contained in the subpackages a and b. But when I try to import the functions I get a module not found error.

```
from package.subpackage_a import hello_world_a 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.subpackage_a'
```

and the same thing holds for subpackage_b. But if I import package this is recognised. I have a feeling that this approach used to work, as I have some old packages written this way which don't work any longer.

Perhaps I have to change my **init**.py files ?  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you import `package` and check `package.__file__`, do you get the disk location you expect? Perhaps you have a stray file named `package.py` around somewhere (or another version of your package), and that gets found first in the module search order.

Comment: thanks for your comment: yes the file is in the correct location, in the site-packages  of the virtualenv. This happened with several attempts I have done with different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setuptools.setup` doesn't know that `subpackage_a` and `subpackage_b` exist. You only specified the top-level `package`. So it won't include these subpackages in the installation. Instead you should also specify them:

```
setup(
    ...,
    packages=['package', 'subpackage_a', 'subpackage_b']
)
```

This process can be automatized via `find_packages()`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    ...,
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is working now. Can I ask if something has changed recently or was this always the case ? The structure I showed used to work in my old projects. Anyways thank you very much.

Comment: @DuccioPiovani I'm not aware that this is the result of a recent change. But maybe you could bring "old" a bit more in context? How old are these projects in terms of version numbers? Or maybe you installed those other projects in editable (`-e`) mode?

Comment: sorry you are right, by old I meant everything until 2019. But your observation is 100% correct I usually installed them in -e mode. Does that explain it ? thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @DuccioPiovani Yes, when you install in `-e` mode it will effectively place a symlink in your site-packages directory so that when you `import package` it goes and looks inside the directory where the package is being developed (i.e. no files are copied during installation, which is what happens without the `-e` switch). This is similar as if you were sitting at the parent directory of `package` and from there you can of course import subpackages. The thing is that `pip install .` copies all the relevant files (+ subdirectories) but omits them if not specified via `packages=[...]`.